# Zoho API C# ERROR: "OAUTH_SCOPE_MISMATCH", "status": "error", "message": "invalid oauth scope to access this URL"

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, oauth, zoho

I have a problem with authorization throught C# code fro Zoho API. I already tried it with Postman and it's working. I can create a Lead if I will use Postman, but I need to do it in C# code. I'm using ZOHOCRMSDK-2.1 version.

They have API Console, where I created
[image]

I have client_secret, client_id and all what I need.

For the C# app I'm using WebAPI, so it should work there. I also created appsettings.json and put there all credentials which I need:
[image]

I'm getting this error, when I'm trying to GET all accounts which I have in ZohoCRM:
[image]

I'm not getting error here, but I'm getting it in the next section of my code. My code is below:

```
public static void Get(Settings settings)
        {

            Logger logger = new Logger.Builder().Level(Logger.Levels.ALL).FilePath("/Users/matias/csharp_sdk_log.log").Build();

            UserSignature user = new UserSignature(settings.Email);

            Environment environment = EUDataCenter.PRODUCTION;

            Token token = new OAuthToken.Builder()
                .ClientId(settings.ClientId)
                .ClientSecret(settings.ClientSecret)
                .RefreshToken(settings.RefreshToken)
                .Build();

            TokenStore tokenStore = new FileStore("C:\\TokenStore\\sdktoken.txt");

            SDKConfig config = new SDKConfig.Builder().AutoRefreshFields(true).PickListValidation(true).Build();

            new SDKInitializer.Builder()
                .User(user)
                .Environment(environment)
                .Token(token)
                .Store(tokenStore)
                .SDKConfig(config)
                //.ResourcePath(resourcePath)
                .Logger(logger)
                .Initialize();

            GetRecordsContacts("Accounts");
        }
```

Next section of my code:

```
public static void GetRecordsContacts(string moduleAPIName)
{
            RecordOperations recordOperations = new RecordOperations();
            ParameterMap paramInstance = new ParameterMap();
            paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PAGE, 1);
            paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.PER_PAGE, 200);
            paramInstance.Add(GetRecordsParam.APPROVED, "both");

            HeaderMap headerInstance = new HeaderMap();
            APIResponse<ResponseHandler> response = recordOperations.GetRecords(moduleAPIName, paramInstance, headerInstance);
}
```

So, why it's not working with C# code, but it's working in Postman? What I'm missing here?

Comment: Well the error says the scope you are sending is invalid.  I would start there.   Figure out what scope your sending and check zoho to see what scopes they support.

Comment: @DaImTo All the examples that they have in public there is no scope in c# implementation. The question is why I can create a lead in Postman with the same credential, but can not in C#? That's an interesting part.

Comment: My question is how are you authorizing in postman you haven't included that code.

Comment: @DaImTo what it will change? If I have all my credentials in C# code. I can see that no one can help me with that.

Comment: because from what i can see in your C# code your not sending a scope. I cant even see how you are authorizing the application in C# it looks like your just feeding it the client credentials and a refresh token.   Where is the C# authorization code where is C# getting the refresh token from?

Comment: @DaImTo I used Postman to get refresh token, so I just copy it and put in appsettings.json and now I'm using it. I have client_id and client_secret also there. My access token I will get in Token token as I understood. You can check their documentation: https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/csharp-sdk/v1/initialize.html Maybe you will find something that I can't find.

Comment: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/invalid-oauth-scope-to-access-this-urloauth-scope-mismatch